# Is it possible to make color resources private in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-productflavors

I was wondering if its possible to have private color resources in android?

Eg:
Files in main:
colors.xml:

```
  <color name="red">#520A2A</color>
  <color name="red_darken_1">#A11453</color>
```

Files in flavor 1:
element_colors.xml:

```
  <color name="header_color">@colors/red</color>
  <color name="footer_color">@color/red_darken_1</color>
```

Files in flavor 2:
colors.xml:

```
  <color name="blue">#041B3F</color>
  <color name="blue_darken_1">#244B77</color>
```

element_colors.xml:

```
  <color name="header_color">@colors/blue</color>
  <color name="footer_color">@color/blue_darken_1</color>
```

Now I don't want people to use colors in layout files or styles from colors.xml, but I always want them to use it from element_colors.xml so that the app does not become specific to a single flavor. 
Basically, how to make some color files inaccessible to layouts and styles?

Comment: Resources **are** private to your app only. Except system resources.

Comment: Well, I was talking about a single app codebase itself but with two flavors.

Comment: Hrundi is wright, Your resources are not accessable by other apps.....

Comment: Comments here regarding external Resources are incorrect. Please see  `PackageManager#getResourcesForApplication()` and related methods. Also, that's not what the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make resources private for a **library**.

Please have look at the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources).

and specifically, note the trick,

> All resources in a library default to public. To make all resources implicitly private, you must define at least one specific attribute as public.